# Forever errors with babel-node

Tags: node.js, forever, babeljs, pm2

I have a simple node server:

//server.js

```
import express  from 'express';
import React    from 'react';
...
```

When I try to run this using [Forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever):

`forever start -c "babel-node --experimental" server.js`
, it errors out due to use of `import`

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/React/ReactBoilerplates/koba04/app/server.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import express  
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
```

I have also tried [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2) and [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon), I get same error there as well.
For pm2, I followed this issue https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/issues/1167, but it didn't work either. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: With PM2 just do:
```pm2 start app.js --interpreter ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node```

Comment: It appears you forgot to define .babelrc file with presets by default

Answer (score 10):

```
forever start -c "node -r babel-register" ./src/index.js
```

Also works.

Answer (score 8):

This works for on-the-fly transpilation for me: `forever start -c node_modules/.bin/babel-node server.js`

Another solution is using the [Require Hook](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/) like this:

```
// server-wrapper.js
require('babel/register');

require('./server.js');
```

Then run `forever start server-wrapper.js`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to precompile your `es6` scripts into `es5` scripts and run the app with a `forever start server.js` command where `server.js` is a result of precompilation.

If you're using react.js for an isomorphic app you also will be needed to precompile your scripts for browsers either (via `browserify`, `webpack` and so on).

So I see no profit to work with `es6` scripts via on demand compilation versus precompilation with `gulp` or any other js building system.

Comment: Did you mean to say "compilation" instead of "compilcation" throughout?

Comment: The profit is obvious: You don't need to precompile.

Answer (score 0):

In your `package.json` file under `scripts` tag add entry like below

in `package.json` under `scripts` tag

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "forever start -c babel-node src/index.js",
},
```

all the dependencies must include in dependencies tag in `package.json` file

then do a `npm install` then
run the server by executing `npm start`